How to fix the "xclock" on a ubuntu VirtualBox?
On windows 10 I run a VirtualBox with ubuntu 22.04.2 and when I start the xclock with
xclock -digital -fg white

I see this window:

Is there a way to fix this? xclock without parameter works, but I need to have a digital clock with seconds.
The command
xclock -digital -fg white -bg black

gives:

Also, when I open a normal terminal, this is how the top bar looks like:

again these hieroglyphs ...
It is definitively the VM, because when I turn off Display -> Enable 3D Acceleration then I see the terminal title bar and xclock -digital works as expected. However, in that settings I see my mouse cursor often as a black square and the whole windows are flickering and jumping around, making the VM virtually useless.
Is there a way to fix this WITHOUT reinstalling the VM (which I have dome way too often already)?
VirtualBox 7.0.20
I tried to create a simple python script using tkinter to show the clock in digital format -> Shows the same kind of hieroglyphs ...

... so you are likely setting the foregound (i.e. text) color the same as the background color - try either something like xclock -digital -fg white -bg black (for white on black) or simply plain xclock -digital (for the default black on white)

On a separate note your Ubuntu OS is behind in updates. A fully updated system is 22.04.4

When I try xclick -digital then I see ONLY black. So like the image but without the three white "things"

Hmm... so I wonder if your desktop theme is messing with things (perhaps inverting colors)?

I do not remember to have changed anything. But I will try to check the desktop theme. But I fear it will screw up everything ...

If you install xterm, you can use date with a suitable configuration string and get something very similar to xclock -digital ..., for example
xterm -fa default -fs 12 -title 'my clock' -geometry 24x2 -e bash -c 'while true; do date +"%a %Y-%m-%d_%H.%M.%S";sleep 1;done' 2>/dev/null


On Ubuntu 24.04
Hmm... no --version option...
$ file `which xclock`
/usr/bin/xclock: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV),  
dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2,  
BuildID[sha1]=43b56fee78570f716f70671eab030c5a8286ce5a,  
for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, stripped

$ xclock -digital -fg white -bg black  # OK
$ xclock -digital -fg white            # all white, white text on white bg?
$ xclock -digital           -bg black  # all black, black text on black bg
$ xclock -digital                      # OK.

... here I'd say this is the classic fg==bg, nothing else...

I have a workaround: I start the python script to show the current time on windows and drag that window on top of the VM screen. That way, I have the time in a moveable window on top of any other VM-Linux application...
